# Support for injection of Func<TService> factories in Spring .NET

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, factory, spring.net

I'm looking for generic support of Func factory injection in Spring .NET - the same functionality which provides [Typed Factory Facility for Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-delegate-based-factories.ashx), but I'm not able to figure out how to support this kind of factory injection in Spring. Is there any extension point in Spring I could use to support this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not supported out-of-the-box. However, it is possible to create an `IFactoryObject` that simply executes a `Func<T>` on the `GetObject()` call. See for instance [this implementation on github](https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-esb/blob/master/Rhino.ServiceBus.Spring/ApplicationContextExtensions.cs#L95) (by one of the regular Spring.net committers) where a `FuncBasedObjectCreator<T> : IFactoryObject` is used.

In the example, you'll see that the author also created several extension for `IConfigurableApplicationContext` that utilize this `FuncBasedObjectCreator`.